# Can Minor Conjuration create an object that weighs less than the original?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, wizard

Conjuration wizard's feature *Minor Conjuration* states:

> Starting at 2nd level when you select this school, you can use your action to conjure up an inanimate object in your hand or on the ground in an unoccupied space that you can see within 10 feet of you. This object can be no larger than 3 feet on a side and **weigh no more than 10 pounds**, and its **form** must be that of a nonmagical object that you have seen.

Does that mean that I can conjure that is shaped (i.e has the same form) like an object I have seen, but weighs less?

E.g a hunting trap normally weighs 25 pounds. If I want to leave an impression that a certain area is trapped, can I conjure up a 10 pound (albeit glowing) hunting trap of the same size and leave it there? Currently I am not particularly interested if the trap might not function the same (or at all) because it has different weight.

Comment: I am struggling to resist the urge to bring Platonism and the [Theory of Forms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theory_of_forms) into this.

Comment: Related: [Limitations on the Conjurer's Minor Conjuration ability](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/47885), and very related: [Can you conjure a small version of a vehicle with Minor Conjuration and use Enlarge/Reduce to grow it into a copy of the original vehicle?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/148685)

Comment: What do you mean by glowing hunting trap? Non-magical objects don't normally glow, unless they are radioactive or something.

Comment: @AllanMills I mean the next sentence of the feature description that I didn't include for the sake of brevity: "The object is visibly magical,
radiating dim light out to 5 feet."

Answer (score 2):

### I don't see why not, with some caveats.

Since you expressly state that the trap is going to be non-functional, I see no reason a spellcaster couldn't summon a 10-pound, fake hunting trap.

One caveat is "**Has the character ever seen a fake hunting trap?**" By strict RAW it'll take the form of an object the character has seen, and it could be argued that a fake, lightweight hunting trap is a different type of object than a real one.

But honestly as a DM, I'd let that slide, because as you point out, it's all about the **form** of the object.

Another caveat is "**Could someone tell that it's fake?**" (given your desire to leave the impression that an area is trapped) and here I'd have to say the answer is "yes" - both because the trap is non-functional and underweight and *glowing*.

But as a DM I'd probably rule this would be a contested skill check between spellcasting ability and perception (Note: all skill checks are DM's discretion, so this isn't RAW)

But worth noting this would require an action to examine the trap, so it'd be effective in combat, at least.

Answer (score 0):

#### It mostly depends on the DM

If a hunting trap weighs 25 pounds, then even a non-functional one made from the same material would weigh more or less the same.

Having said that, if your DM would allow you to conjure a non-functional or even a functional hunting trap that is made from some kind of lighter material that iron or steel (ex. Aluminium, which would be 2.5 times lighter than steel), it could still look kind of convincing that is real, and would abide by the rules.

Comment: Are you saying that I can change the material of object but only to "real" materials? If so why? E.g. why can't the new material be "steel but 3x lighter" or "the stuff that Tenser's Floating Disk is made of"?

Comment: Again I think that this would be the DM's decision to allow or not. The ablity states that the object created can weigh up to 10 pounds and it's form has to be of an object you have seen. Having said that, it doesn't specify that the object has to be from the same material as the real one, so technically speaking, the sky is the limit. Now about tenser's floating disk, it's not really made from a certain material but from pure force as stated in the spells description, so I don't believed this can be used. As a DM tho I would allow only materials that exist in the Faerun.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the *flavor* features that its usefulness depends on your creativity. You are asking about something undefined in the description: conjuring a mini-version of an object. The answer is **depends on the DM.**

As a DM, as long as you are following the hard limitations (usually numerical values), I'd allow broad interpretation of terms used for limitation, such as '**form**' and '**you've seen**'. Only, when I find the implementation problematic, I'd negotiate a requirement for it to work; otherwise, go wild! Amuse me!